# PyQt5 not adding items to List Widget in another function

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I have the following simple code, and for some reason `addItem()` does not add an item to the List Widget in the app's UI in the `exec_all()` function. `add_item()` works perfectly fine outside of that function. Ive added the smallest snippet of the relevant code below:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from time import sleep

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
dlg = uic.loadUi("Program.ui")

def exec_all():
    dlg.OutputConsole.addItem("Test")
    web_scrap()
    # etc...

# web_scrap(): A function in another file that 
# scraps data from website. It needs to wait for
# HTML elements to fully load into DOM at times 
# by using time.sleep()
def web_scrap(dlg):
    sleep(5)

dlg.RunAllButton.clicked.connect(exec_all)

dlg.show()
app.exec()
```

**UPDATE**: Ive discovered where the problem lies by updating code snippet above to reproduce the problem -- it seems like `addItem()` does not want to execute before `sleep()` is called later, which is very odd to me unless `addItem()` is an asynchronous function? Will i have to use another method other than `sleep()` in `web_scrap()` in order to get around this problem?

Comment: Sorry but that code is completely insufficient. Please provide an appropriate [mre].

Comment: Ive updated the code snippet that reproduces the problem. By doing so, ive discovered that the problem lies when calling sleep(). That is, addItem() only updates the UI AFTER sleep(), and not before

Comment: This is expected: operations such as `sleep()` or while/for loops are *blocking*, meaning that they prevent the event loop to properly process events, including requests for updates (aka: redraw widgets when required). If you add a `print(dlg.OutputConsole.count())` after `addItem()` you'll see that it will properly print the correct element count of the list widget. Note that using an arbitrary time to wait for another "process" to end is a terrible idea: on a fast computer, you'll be waiting too much, on a slow one it will resume while the process hasn't completed yet.

Comment: In any case, if a time consuming operation doesn't need any communication with the UI, the `threading` module will suffice, but for short operations you may even consider calling [`QApplication.processEvents()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents). If you instead *do* need to interact with the UI (for example, to notify a finished "job"), you **must** use Qt signals/slots, because UI elements are ***not*** thread-safe; this means using QThread (either by subclassing, or to manage a QObject "worker" subclass) or eventually a QRunnable with a QObject "proxy" to emit signals.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to take your time and do some proper research on *all* the above topics, because there are plenty of related resources even here on StackOverflow, as you can see from the list of posts (which is just a partial compendium) for which I marked your question as duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for your strong suggestion, I couldn't have known my problem with addItems() had to do with threads. I read you in your respondes as not recommending sleep(), however for web scraping projects its often the only solution when all other solutions have been exhausted. But now ill be more prepared in the future if such problems occur again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it was indeed the `sleep()` pausing execution of the entire thread of my pyqt app. This also caused my pyqt app to hang upon button click. See below for solution.

**General problem**: Some arbitrary amount of code wont run before a time.sleep() invocation in your python program.

**Solution**: Create a new thread for that problematic snippet of code by using the `threading` python module. For example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
dlg = uic.loadUi("Program.ui")

def problematic_code():
    # ...
    sleep(5)
    # ...

def new_thread():
    newThread = Thread(target=problematic_code)
    newThread.start()


dlg.ButtonInYourApp.clicked.connect(new_thread)
```

Creating a second thread will allow your code to continue running as expected as well as keep your pyqt app from hanging with the spinning wheel.